# Relationship between html table columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, html-table

I appreciate this is probably quite simple, however I can find no support for this in any HTML tutorials or forums...

I'm trying to create a table in wordpress without the use of a plugin as I do not want to be restricted and would really like to be able to fully customise the table as the site grows.

The probably I'm having is make certain columns dependent on others. An example is the there's a cost per mile column, which is obviously the number of miles divided by the cost of entry. Without having to manually enter the division each time, is there a way I can make the cost per mile column = to the distance divided by cost?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: This is certainly not possible with HTML & CSS. You would need Javascript/PHP etc

Comment: you need another programming language to do this. javascript, PHP etc

Comment: Where are you pulling your data from? A simple math task like that could easily be tacked onto a SQL query without major performance concerns.